# Terminal error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "['polyfills']" should be array

Tags: angular, jestjs, cypress

I have just created a new angular app using the `ng new <projectName>`. I then changed the default testing setup by using `ng add @cypress/schematic` and `ng add @briebug/jest-schematic`

`package.lock` for reference:

```
{
  "name": "betting-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.2",
    "@briebug/jest-schematic": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "latest",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^1.5.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jest": "latest",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2",
    "cypress": "latest"
  }
}
```

When I run `ng test` I get the above error and am struggling with how to get my tests to run. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so whoever is finding this in 2023 and after, this is what you should do - go to your `angular.json` file, find the `test` object and make the `polyfills` and the `inlineStyleLanguage` an array like so:

```
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts"
            ],
            "inlineStyleLanguage": [
              "scss"
            ],
          }
        },
```

And you should be good to go.

If you are trying to import JS files (like Lodash functions), you should also add the following line to your `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx|(?!deck.gl)|ng-dynamic)'],
};
```

This will prevent the TS transformation error ('SyntaxError: Unexpected token export').

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/1030) from searching Google.

> Why do you need `polyfills` entry in your `test` target at all when
> using `@angular-builders/jest` builder?
> [Here](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/jest/src/schema.json)
> is the builder's schema, it doesn't contain a `polyfills` field. The
> reason you're getting this error is that all the additional
> (non-schema) fields are considered [an array of
> strings](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/jest/src/schema.json#L485)
> (so that you'd be able to pass filenames to `ng test` just like you
> pass them to `jest`).
>
> My guess is that `polyfills` is a leftover from Karma builder and you can
> safely remove it. The only options needed in `angular.json` are those
> mentioned
> [here](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest#builder-options).

Comment: Please summarize your researches and write your own answer.

Comment: in.ts:7 Error: NG0908: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
    at new NgZone (core.mjs:26076:19)
    at getNgZone (core.mjs:27075:75)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.mjs:26942:24)
    at core.mjs:26998:41
(

Comment: I got that error