# How can I fix the following error: Data path "/polyfills" must be string in my angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, build

I am using NodeJS version 18. I  am trying to deploy my Angular app to Firebase and/or run it successfully on my local, but I am unable to do so.
[link to package.json and source code] -> https://github.com/anshumankmr/jovian-genai-hackathon/blob/master/UI/package.json

I have tried a lot of things but I am unable to figure it out.
For example, in my angular.json file, I tried this:

[image]

and this

[image].

Then I tried running 'npm run build'
I got the following error however.

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI/zone.js' in '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI'

I have seen these links, but they are asking to modify a file here called polyfills.ts which doesn't exist in my codebase.
[Angular2 Final Release - "Error: Angular requires Zone.js prolyfill"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592949/angular2-final-release-error-angular-requires-zone-js-prolyfill)

And this describes the exact opposite of what my current problem is : [Terminal error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "['polyfills']" should be array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826552/terminal-error-schema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errors-data-path)

Comment: Angular 14 isn't compatible with Node18: [more details here](https://angular.io/guide/versions)

Comment: The guy who helped me develop this told me he was using Node 18 :| Will try with a lower version of node... thanks @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Getting the same error @JacopoSciampi. I used nvm to switch 14.15 version

Comment: >Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI/zone.js' in '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cloned the repo and made some changes to make it works.

In the `tsconfig.app.json` add the line

> "src/polyfills.ts"

in the `files` array.

In the `angular.json` file, transform the `polyfills` array to be a string:

> "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts"

Then create a file named `polyfills.ts` with the content:

> import 'zone.js'

in the `src` folder.

You can now serve the application.

Angular14 doesn't seems to support the *new* schema, but I've not managed to find any article about it. If you want to benefit from all the new stuff I suggest you to update your project to the latest LTS (At the time of this answer, the version 15).

EDIT:

My tests were done using NodeJS version 18.16.0 and NPM 9.6.7

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check the MR.

Comment: I was able to replicate this and patch the issue. Thank you @Jacopo Sciampi